# Need help to write a query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
Col Col A   Col B
A   1.2 -3
B   0.7 3.1
C   0.75    -0.77
D   13  -6
E   -2.45   1.94
F   -0.2    0.88
A   3.5 2.7
B   -1.5    1.34
C   -2.3    0.06
D   3.2 1.9
A   1.2 -2.3
B   -3  1.1
C   3.3 -1.1
```

I need to write a query to get the following output

Columns

```
Tenor, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, ....... , 10 (0 to 10)
```

Sum of Count of  Col A and Col B where Col values are >= the abs values of the columns

For 0 count all the abs values in Col A and Col B group by Tenor where abs(value) > 0

For 0.5 count all the abs values in Col A and Col B group by Tenor where abs(value) > 0.5

```
Col 0   0.5 1   1.5 2   2.5 …..
A   6   6   6   4   4   3   …..
B   6   6   5   3   2   2   …..
C   6   5   3   2   2   1   …..
D   4   4   4   4   3   3   …..
E   2   2   2   2   1   0   …..
F   2   1   0   0   0   0   …..
```

and so on. Output should be like the above table

Comment: Sample data, expected results, and your attempts will help us help you here.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour] and to read [ask]. Then, please read the guidelines in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and edit your question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds pretty simple, but you've given us no sample data.Tenor?

Comment: Is this not just `COUNT(CASE WHEN ColA + ColB >= 0 THEN 1 END) AS [0]`?

Comment: Tenor is the first column, which I have renamed it as Col.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to add the columns dynamically. Change the parameter of top 41 to the number of columns you desire and if you wish to change the step size then alter the value of 0.5 to your desired step.

```
DECLARE @query_string as NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @cols         as NVARCHAR(MAX) 



with data
  as (
      select top 41 (row_number() over(order by (select null))-1)*0.5 as rnk
         from master..spt_values
      )
     ,cols_data
      as(
select ',count(case when abs(a.col_a)>='+cast(rnk as varchar(10)) +' then 1 end) + '
       +'count(case when abs(a.col_b)>='+cast(rnk as varchar(10)) +' then 1 end) as ['+cast(rnk as varchar(10))+'] '+ CHAR(10) as col
  from data
        )
 select @cols = string_agg(col, ' ') 
   from cols_data
        


SET @query_string = 'SELECT a.col ' +CHAR(10)
                   +        @cols 
                   +' from t a '+CHAR(10)
           +'GROUP BY a.col'
           
           
execute(@query_string)  




+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| col | 0.0 | 0.5 | 1.0 | 1.5 | 2.0 | 2.5 | 3.0 | 3.5 | 4.0 | 4.5 | 5.0 | 5.5 | 6.0 | 6.5 | 7.0 | 7.5 | 8.0 | 8.5 | 9.0 | 9.5 | 10.0 | 10.5 | 11.0 | 11.5 | 12.0 | 12.5 | 13.0 | 13.5 | 14.0 | 14.5 | 15.0 | 15.5 | 16.0 | 16.5 | 17.0 | 17.5 | 18.0 | 18.5 | 19.0 | 19.5 | 20.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| A   |   6 |   6 |   6 |   4 |   4 |   3 |   2 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| B   |   6 |   6 |   5 |   3 |   2 |   2 |   2 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| C   |   6 |   5 |   3 |   2 |   2 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| D   |   4 |   4 |   4 |   4 |   3 |   3 |   3 |   2 |   2 |   2 |   2 |   2 |   2 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| E   |   2 |   2 |   2 |   2 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| F   |   2 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

DB Fiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e2dc12c878fb75515e9aad2eb503c26a

Comment: Perfect. Thanks much.

Comment: Please mark it as the answer and upvote if you like my answer

Comment: looks like string_agg is not supported by sql 2016, can I have a 2016 alternative?

Comment: You should be able to make use of STUFF keyword to get this done

Comment: Here is a dbfiddle example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36411544cdd70e0af4ac39e591551654

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this

```
select a.col
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=0   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=0   then 1 end) as [0]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=0.5   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=0.5   then 1 end) as [0.5]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=1   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=1   then 1 end) as [1]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=1.5   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=1.5   then 1 end) as [1.5]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=2   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=2   then 1 end) as [2]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=2.5   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=2.5   then 1 end) as [2.5]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=3   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=3   then 1 end) as [3]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=3.5   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=3.5   then 1 end) as [3.5]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=4   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=4   then 1 end) as [4]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=4.5   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=4.5   then 1 end) as [4.5]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=5   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=5   then 1 end) as [5]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=5.5   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=5.5   then 1 end) as [5.5]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=6   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=6   then 1 end) as [6]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=6.5   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=6.5   then 1 end) as [6.5]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=7   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=7   then 1 end) as [7]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=7.5   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=7.5   then 1 end) as [7.5]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=8   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=8   then 1 end) as [8]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=8.5   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=8.5   then 1 end) as [8.5]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=9   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=9   then 1 end) as [9]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=9.5   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=9.5   then 1 end) as [9.5]
       ,count(case when abs(a.col_a)>=10   then 1 end)  + count(case when abs(a.col_b)>=10   then 1 end) as [10]
  from t a
group by a.col  



+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+----+
| col | 0 | 0.5 | 1 | 1.5 | 2 | 2.5 | 3 | 3.5 | 4 | 4.5 | 5 | 5.5 | 6 | 6.5 | 7 | 7.5 | 8 | 8.5 | 9 | 9.5 | 10 |
+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+----+
| A   | 6 |   6 | 6 |   4 | 4 |   3 | 2 |   1 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 |  0 |
| B   | 6 |   6 | 5 |   3 | 2 |   2 | 2 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 |  0 |
| C   | 6 |   5 | 3 |   2 | 2 |   1 | 1 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 |  0 |
| D   | 4 |   4 | 4 |   4 | 3 |   3 | 3 |   2 | 2 |   2 | 2 |   2 | 2 |   1 | 1 |   1 | 1 |   1 | 1 |   1 |  1 |
| E   | 2 |   2 | 2 |   2 | 1 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 |  0 |
| F   | 2 |   1 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 | 0 |   0 |  0 |
+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+----+
```

Comment: Yes result is correct. Can we make the condition more dynamic? Suppose we want to make it till 20 instead of 10 then we may have to add 20 more lines.

Comment: Well you would need to build the query string dynamically to get this done

Comment: With String Manipulation, Variables and a Loop you can build a dynamic query.